# How to serialize JSON string to multidimensional NSDictionary

Tags: json, swift, nsdictionary

```
"[{\"person\":\"person1\",\"data\":{\"age\":\"10\",\"name\":\"John\"}},
{\"person\":\"person2\",\"data\":{\"age\":\"20\",\"name\":\"Jonathan\"}},
{\"person\":\"person3\",\"data\":{\"age\":\"30\",\"name\":\"Joe\"}}]"
```

Note that the value "data" is also a dictionary.

I have a JSON string like above and am trying to serialize like:

```
if let dataFromString = conf.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {
        let json = try JSON(data: dataFromString)
        
        configuration = json.dictionary ?? [:]
    }
```

However configuration is always an empty dictionary.

Comment: The [ ] indicates a root json array, not a dictionary. `.dictionary` is probably incorrect, maybe there is a `.array` depending on the JSON library you are using.

Comment: Yes, but it is always a single element array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the `JSON` you've as an `array` of `dictionaries` of type `[[String: Any]]`. The better modern approach is to use `Decodable` model to decode the `JSON`.

```
let string = """
[
    {
        "person": "person1",
        "data": {
            "age": "10",
            "name": "John"
        }
    },
    {
        "person": "person2",
        "data": {
            "age": "20",
            "name": "Jonathan"
        }
    },
    {
        "person": "person3",
        "data": {
            "age": "30",
            "name": "Joe"
        }
    }
]
"""

let data = Data(string.utf8)

struct Person: Decodable {
    let person: String
    let data: PersonData
}

struct PersonData: Decodable {
    let age, name: String
}

do {
    let people = try JSONDecoder().decode([Person].self, from: data)
    print(people)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the *JSON* `String`,

```
let conf = "[{\"person\":\"person1\",\"data\":{\"age\":\"10\",\"name\":\"John\"}},{\"person\":\"person2\",\"data\":{\"age\":\"20\",\"name\":\"Jonathan\"}},{\"person\":\"person3\",\"data\":{\"age\":\"30\",\"name\":\"Joe\"}}]"
```

use `JSONSerialization's` **`jsonObject(with:options:)`** method to get the expected response.

```
if let conf = str.data(using: .utf8 ) {
    do {
        let dict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String:Any]]
        print(dict)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```